# Template function does not work with dynamic size array

Tags: c++

I tried to write a function to sum the items inside an array:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
T sumItems(T (&arrayOfInt)[N]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += arrayOfInt[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    cout << "Plese enter the number of elements: ";
    int numOfElements;
    cin >> numOfElements;

    int arrayOfInts[numOfElements];

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++) {
        cin >> arrayOfInts[i];
    }

    int sum = sumItems(arrayOfInts);

    cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler told me "there is no matching function for call to 'sumItems'".
However, if I change

```
int arrayOfInts[numOfElements];
```

to

```
int arrayOfInts[5];
```

The code works without problem.

I know there should be some better solutions to do this (like using vector instead of array). But I'd like to know why it has such a behaviour and how to avoid that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Variable sized array does not work with standard C++.

Comment: Just one more reason to not use this non standard extension.  Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @CoryKramer I am not sure if that dupe is really appropriate.  The real question is why you cannot pass a VLA to a template function taking an array by reference.

Comment: Templates are resolved at compile time, but your `numOfElements` is not known until run time. What do you want to happen (even ignoring non-existence of VLAs in the standard)?